# display value saved in useRef variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-ref

I have a variable

```
const prediction = useRef<any>(null);
```

I click on a button that runs a function which sets the value of my variable:

```
    function showResult() {
        classifier.current.classify(capture, (result) => {
            prediction.current = result[0].label
            console.log('prediction.current', prediction.current)

        });
    }
```

On the console log, I see the correct value for `prediction.current`. However, when I try to render it in JSX, I don't get anything. What can I do to change this?

If I use setState inside the classifier.current.classifyfunction, it gives me different. It's an ml5 function. Is there an alternate way? Could i somehow setState outside the function? useEffect maybe?

```
    return (
    <div>
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => gotResult()}>Test!</Button>
            <br />
            <span>Prediction: {prediction.current}</span><br />
        </div>
    </div>)
```

```
    //const [prediction, setPrediction] = useState<string>();
    //const [confidence, setConfidence] = useState<string>();
    //const [imageClassifier, setClassifier] = useState<any>();

    let capture: p5Types.Element;
    const classifier = useRef<any>(null);
    const prediction = useRef<any>(null);
    const confidence = useRef<any>(null);
    const setup = (p5: p5Types, canvasParentRef: Element) => {
        capture = p5.createCapture(p5.VIDEO).parent(canvasParentRef);
        const featureExtractor = ml5.featureExtractor('MobileNet', modelReady);
        classifier.current = featureExtractor.classification(capture, videoReady);
        console.log('start', classifier);
    }

    function showResult() {
        console.log('classifier in results', classifier);
        classifier.current.classify(capture, (result) => {
            prediction.current = result[0].label;
            console.log(result[0].confidence); // Should output 'dog'

        });
    }
```

Comment: A ref changing will not cause a component to re-render, which is why you probably aren't seeing the value displayed. Is there any reason to not just store that in `useState`? That would trigger the re-render.

Comment: If I use setState inside the ```classifier.current.classify```function, it gives me different. It's an ml5 function. Is there an alternate way? Could i somehow setState outside the function? useEffect maybe? @MarcBaumbach

Comment: @Jdb I'm not sure I follow, but if you have access to the ref from `useRef` in that function, you should be able to call the `useState`'s setter function just fine. The setter function isn't really special other than it automatically triggers a re-render of the component that it's defined in, so you should be able to pass it to whatever is defining that ml5 function similar to however you're getting the ref there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ref changing its `current` value does not trigger any re-renders in React components, but you should be able to replace the snippets above and trigger the re-render to see the latest value:

```js
const prediction = useRef<any>(null);
```

Becomes:

```js
const [prediction, setPrediction] = useState(null);
```

The `getResult` function would then look like:

```js
function gotResult() {
    classifier.current.classify(capture, (err: any, result: any) => {
        setPrediction(result[0].label])
    });
}
```

Finally the rendering:

```
return (
    <div>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={() => gotResult()}>Test!</Button>
        <br />
        <span>Prediction: {prediction}</span><br />
    </div>
)
```

Your `classifier` is setting the `current` value on every render. You probably only want that whenever `featureExtractor`, `capture` or `videoReady` changes. You can do that with `useMemo`:

```js
const classifier = useMemo(() => {
    return featureExtractor.classification(capture, videoReady);
}, [featureExtractor, capture, videoReady]);
```

That dependency array in `useMemo` will make sure the classifier only gets defined if those variables change and not on every render.

Comment: Your classifier looks like it's getting re-assigned on every render. You may need to wrap that in a useMemo (I added that as well).

Comment: but I cannot use useMemo inside the setup function as that would throw an error. i updated detailed code above.

Comment: What calls `setup`? You might need to provide a complete [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or a link to a codesandbox that reproduces it.

Comment: Here's my initial problem along with a codesandbox: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67221199/useref-state-becomes-undefined-after-rendering

Comment: @Jbd I took a stab at modifying the codesandbox in a fork. I'm not sure it's fixed anything with the ML side of things, but I think the hooks (state + ref) stuff looks correct to me. You might give it a shot: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-sea-0pcfx?file=/src/Component.tsx

Comment: Oh yes, it seems to work!! but the only different thing is that you added REF for capture too, right? Along with adding states for prediction. Or did you change something else too?

Comment: Also, i'm planning to add a button which makes resets the classifier so I can do the whole training again. How can I reset the classifier now?

Comment: @Jbd, yes the capture was also needing to be assigned and was all done in the `setup`, so I assigned it to a ref. I suspect, if you want to reset everything, you may need to call `setup` again, though I'm not sure how that `Sketch` component works and whether that'll actually work if you call it or if you need to somehow reset the `Sketch` too. I'm just not familiar with the other technologies there, just React. :) Best of luck!

Comment: If you want, you could post the Codesandbox link in the original other qs, it has a bounty